# Continuously repeat a function until the user says stop?

Tags: c++, function, loops

I'm trying to practice writing a code in C++ using functions, I mostly have it right, except for the final part where I try to prompt the user to ask if they would like to repeat the function one more time.  So far one of two things happens.  Either  the function ends without prompting the user, or the function loops continuously using the entered parameters.

I've tried using a do while loop as well as a simple while loop.  But I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void getTime24(int& hour, int& minute);
bool daylightSavingsTime(bool& DST);
int  convertTime24to12(int hour);
void printTime24(int hour, int minute);
void printTime12(int hour, int hour12, int minute);
void printJapanTime(int hour, int minute, bool DST);
bool userWantsToContinue(bool& repeat);

int main() {
int hour = 0;
int hour12 = 0;
int minute = 0;
bool DST = false;
bool repeat = true;

while (repeat == true) {
    // Enter a time value
    getTime24(hour, minute);

    // Check for daylight savings time
    daylightSavingsTime(DST);
    cout << endl;

    // Convert to 12 hour format
    hour12 = convertTime24to12(hour);

    // Print the time in 24 hour format
    printTime24(hour, minute);
    cout << " in Portland." << endl;

    // Prints out the time and the AM/PM designation (e.g. 14:32 becomes 2:32 PM)
    printTime12(hour, hour12, minute);
    cout << " in Portland." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Prints out the current time in Tokyo
    printJapanTime(hour, minute, DST);
    cout << endl;

    // Continue?
    bool repeat = userWantsToContinue(repeat);
    cout << endl;
    if (repeat == false)
        break;
}

return 0;
}


//FUNCTIONS
//================================================
// This function is to take in and store the 24 hour time.  It stores the times before 
// and after the colon as hours and minutes respectivly, and reads the colon as a char
// then passes all three parts as an input.  The colon is ignored.

void getTime24(int& hour, int& minute) {
char ch;
if (minute == '0') {
    minute = printf("00");
}
else {
    minute = minute;
}

cout << "Enter a time in a 24 hour format (e.g. 14:30): ";
cin >> hour >> ch >> minute;
while (hour > 24 || minute > 59) {
cout << "That is not a valid time.\n";
cout << "Enter a time in a 24 hour format (e.g. 14:30): ";
cin >> hour >> ch >> minute;
}
}
//================================================
// This function checks for daylight savings time which will be used in the time zone
// conversion later.  It takes the first letter of a yes or no answer and turns that
// into a bool answer.

bool daylightSavingsTime(bool& DST) {
char yesNo;
cout << "Is it daylight savings time now? ";
cin >> yesNo;  // Takes only the first letter of the inputed answer to daylight savings

yesNo = tolower(yesNo);  // Converts letter to uppercase to allow for fewer compairsons

if (yesNo == 'y')
    DST = true;
else 
    DST = false;

return DST;
}
//================================================
// This block of code will convert the previously entered 24 hour time and convert it
// to a 12 hour time format.  It will do this by adding 12 to the hours and using the 
// result to determine if the time is AM or PM.  It will return the time to be stored.

int  convertTime24to12(int hour) {
int hour12 = 0;
int timeCheck = hour + 12;

if (timeCheck >= 25) {
    hour12 = timeCheck - 24;
}
else {
    hour12 = timeCheck - 12;
}
return hour12;
}
//================================================
// This block of code will print out the time in a 24 hour format.

void printTime24(int hour, int minute) {

cout << "The current time (24 hour format) is " << hour << ":" << minute;
}
//================================================
// This block of code will print out the 12 hour format of the time by checking the hour
// variable as a reference.  If it detects that it is in the afternoon (i.e. the hour is
// 12 or greater) then it will print out the time as a PM time, otherwise it will print out
// an AM time.

void printTime12(int hour, int hour12, int minute) {

if (hour > 11)
    cout << "The current time (12 hour format) is " << hour12 << ":" << minute << " PM";
else
    cout << "The current time (12 hour format) is " << hour12 << ":" << minute << " AM";
}
//================================================
// This block of code will take daylight savings time into account and convert the current
// time in Portland to the current time in Tokyo.  It will then print out the current time.
// Check time conversions at https://savvytime.com/converter/jst-to-pst/sep-3-2018/11-30am


void printJapanTime(int hour, int minute, bool DST) {
int japanHour = 0;
int japanHour12 = 0;

if (DST == true) {
    if (hour > 8) {
        japanHour = hour - 8; // from hour - 24 hours + 16 hours for the time conversion.
    }
    else {
        japanHour = hour + 16;
    }
    printTime24(japanHour, minute);
    cout << " in Tokyo." << endl;
    japanHour12 = convertTime24to12(japanHour);
    printTime12(japanHour, japanHour12, minute);
    cout << " in Tokyo." << endl;
}
else if (DST == false) {
    if (hour > 7) {
        japanHour = hour - 7; // from hour - 24 hours + 17 hours for the time conversion.
    }
    else {
        japanHour = hour + 17;
    }
    printTime24(japanHour, minute);
    cout << " in Tokyo." << endl;
    japanHour12 = convertTime24to12(japanHour);
    printTime12(japanHour, japanHour12, minute);
    cout << " in Tokyo." << endl;
}
}
//================================================
// This block of code will determine if the user wants to continue the program or not.
// This will be used in a do while loop, as soon as stop becomes true, we exit the loop.

bool userWantsToContinue(bool& repeat) {
char yesNo;

cout << "Would you like to convert another time? ";
cin >> yesNo;

yesNo = toupper(yesNo);  // Converts letter to uppercase to allow for fewer compairsons

if (yesNo == 'Y') {
    repeat = true;
}
else
    repeat = false;
return repeat;
}
//================================================
```

Thanks.

Comment: use a `debugger` and run this code in it and analyse the variables and step through the lines of code and find out the problem .

Comment: The program is exiting properly, and also repeating for me.

Comment: The variable *repeat* is shadowed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop logic is fine, but, as pointed out by Ruks the variable *repeat* is shadowed.

```
bool repeat = true;   // as written in your program, this variable never changes value
                      // let's call it repeat_1

while (repeat)        // here you test repeat_1
{
    // ...

    // Continue?
    bool repeat = userWantsToContinue(repeat); // here you are declaring a second 
                                               // variable named repeat, why?
                                               // let's call it repeat_2
                                               // it hides the var repeat declared outside the loop.
    cout << endl;
    if (repeat == false)                       // this tests repeat_2, and eventually exits the loop
        break;                                 // I guess that's a fix you made to make 
                                               // your program work.
}
assert(repeat == false);   // this assertion would invariably fail, since repeat_1
                           // is still true.
                           // note that repeat_2 is out of scope, it doesn't exist anymore.
```

Fixing is simple

```
bool repeat = true;          
while (repeat)
{
     //...
     repeat = userWantsToContinue(repeat);  // note this is NOT a declaration,
                                            // there is only one variable called repeat
}
assert(repeat == false);   // this assertion would invariably succeed, since
                           // repeat has to be false to exit the loop.
```

Re-using names in an included scope is a common source of bugs. Now you know what you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  There were two problems, actually.

I got rid of the shadowed repeat variable as mentioned by other users above.  In the main function I switched the type of loop to a do...while loop.  I initialized the bool variable to be true so that the loop doesn't exit immediately, so it looks something like this:

```
// FUNCTION
// Asks the user if they want to go again, 
// if they say yes the function repeats, if no then the program ends.
bool userWantsToContinue(bool repeat);

int main()
  bool repeat = true;

  do {
     ...
     // Continue for another iteration of the loop?
    repeat = userWantsToContinue(repeat);
    cout << endl << endl;
  }while(repeat != false);  // while repeat is true, keep doing the loop

...

//============================================================================================
// This block of code will determine if the user wants to continue the program or not.
// This will be used in a do while loop, in main() as soon as stop becomes true, we exit the loop.

bool userWantsToContinue(bool repeat) {
    char yesNo;
    bool repeat1 = 0;

    cout << "Would you like to convert another time? ";
    cin >> yesNo;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    yesNo = toupper(yesNo);  // Converts letter to uppercase to allow for fewer compairsons

    if (yesNo == 'Y') 
        repeat1 = true;
    else if (yesNo == 'N')
        repeat1 = false;

    return repeat1;
}
//============================================================================================
```

Additionally, whenever the user was entering a simple Y or N letter the program would execute like it should, however if they were to enter a full word (i.e. yes or no) then the loop would exit immediately after the program finished one iteration.  I solved this problem by clearing the buffer with the `cin.ignore(NUMBER OF CHARACTERS TO BE IGNORED, 'CHARACTER THAT AUTOMATICALLY CLEARS OUT THE REST OF THE BUFFER IF ENCOUNTERED');` command.

If the buffer has not been cleared then it saves the unused letters (e.g. if you were to enter yes, the program would use the Y, and keep E and S in the buffer for later).  Later on in the program when it asks the user if they would like to continue for another loop the compiler automatically enters the next letter in the buffer (in our example, E from YES).  By clearing out the buffer immediately after using a letter this solves the problem.

So for example, I had a block of code that asked the user if it was currently daylight savings time.  Before I had this block of code:

```
bool daylightSavingsTime(bool& DST) {
char yesNo;
cout << "Is it daylight savings time now? ";
cin >> yesNo;  // Takes only the first letter of the inputted answer to daylight savings

yesNo = tolower(yesNo);  // Converts letter to uppercase to allow for fewer compairsons

if (yesNo == 'y')
    DST = true;
else 
    DST = false;

return DST;
}
```

After adding in `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` I cleared out the extra unused letters.  In this case I said, to ignore the next 100 characters, or continue when a new line (\n) is encountered.

So now my fixed code looks like this:

```
bool daylightSavingsTime(bool& DST) {
    char yesNo;
    cout << "Is it daylight savings time now? ";
    cin >> yesNo;  // Reads only the first letter of the inputted word to daylight savings time
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');  // clears all of the other characters that weren't used (e.g. 'es' in 'yes')

    yesNo = toupper(yesNo);  // Converts letter to uppercase to allow for fewer compairsons

    if (yesNo == 'Y')  // if the inputted word/letter begins with a Y do set the value of DST to true
        DST = true;
    else  // if the inputted word/letter does not begin with a Y then set the value of DST to false
        DST = false;

    return DST;
}
```

Incidentally, the else statement is the reason why the loop was exiting early when the buffer was not cleared beforehand.  In our YES example, the E was the next character in the buffer.  Since E was not used immediately it was saved for later.  Later on in the code when it asks the user if they would like to do another loop, the same logic is used.  If the program encountered a Y it would continue, if it encountered anything else it would stop.  Since the E in our YES example was saved, and because E is not a Y, the program decided it was time to end.